# Rails one-to-one works for belongs_to but not for has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-one

I have 2 tables **scenarios** and **rental_details**.

The relationships are:

- **rental_details** belongs_to **scenarios**
- **scenarios** has_one **rental_detail**

In the rental_details table I have the scenario_id as a column (note this is as data type INTEGER and not FOREIGN_KEY).

If I run the following in rails console:

```
rental_details_1 = RentalDetail.find(123)
rental_details_1.id
=> 123
rental_details.scenario.id
=> 22 #i.e. this is linked to scenario with id = 22
```

However, if I do the following:

```
scenario_1 = Scenario.find(22)
scenario_1.id
=> 22
scenario_1.rental_details.id
```

I receive the following error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `rental_details' for
>
> Did you mean?  rental_detail
>                  rental_detail=

If I change it to `scenario_1.rental_details.id` I still receive an error.

If I have a one-to-one relationship such as this, can I not access the `rental_details` table from the scenario object?  I thought that the foreign key is in the "belongs_to" table I can automatically call its contents from the "has_one" table's object.

(Sorry, I'm new to coding so my terminology is most probably wrong at points).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the convention:

`Scenario has_one RentalDetail` => scenario_1.rental_detail.id ([has_one docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_on)). It uses the singular form of RentalDetail.

```
class Scenario < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :rental_detail
end
```

`Scenario has_many RentalDetail` => scenario_1.rental_detail**s**.pluck(:id) ([has_many docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many)). It uses the pluralized version of RentalDetail.

```
class Scenario < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :rental_details
end
```

As I said, this is the convetion but nobody stops you from naming the associations as you like. You just need to tell the ActiveRecord to use correct `class_name`, `primary_key`, `foreign_key`, etc. Check the docs.

Comment: I have checked the docs but the issue here is that I have used the correct convention (i.e. everything is in the singular for this one-to-one relationship), however, I still cannot access the rental_detail data from the scenario object I create.

Comment: You have to name you association at "singular", rental_detail. I has to work. That is the convention. `scenario_1.rental_detail.id` - there's no `s` at the end of rental_detail.

Comment: Here are the models and associations I am currently using: class Scenario < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property
  has_one :rental_detail
end
and class RentalDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :scenario
end
As you can see, everything is in the singular.  I still receive the NoMethodError

Comment: I've rerun everything and it now works.  I can confirm that once all is in the singular it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior.

You're still accessing the correct object — a RentalDetail object. If a Scenario has_many RentalDetail, then it'd be accessed using the pluralized form.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If this is the expected behaviour, how can I get the rental_details id for the scenario object?